# How to prove $E\left[\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n\left(X_i-\mu\right)^2\right]=\sigma^2$

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

Suppose we sample some data points $X_{i}$ from $N(\mu, \sigma)$ of which we only know the value of $\mu$, and we want to estimate $\sigma$. How to prove:

$$E\left[\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n\left(X_i-\mu\right)^2\right]=\sigma^2$$

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Use this facts to prove the equality:

- The operator $\text{E}$ is linear.
- For any aleatory variable $X$, its variance is defined as
  $$\sigma^2=\text{E}\!\left[(X-\mu)^2\right].$$
- The $X_i$ belong to $N(\mu,\sigma)$.

Comment: Whoa, I learned a new word today "aleatory."

Comment: @SeanRoberson you may have heard of the Latin phrase "alea iacta est"

Comment: Doesn't the word aleatory exist?